# Sum of hours between multiple dates

Tags: php, mysql

I need to add up the time but subtracting the time when the status is "STOP". Can I make a SQL query or do I need to combine SQL + PHP?
I was given such a database.

```
ID Date                 Status
1  2020.11.02 15:00     New 
1  2020.11.02 15:00     Start 
1  2020.11.02 15:05     Stop   
1  2020.11.02 15:10     Start
1  2020.11.02 16:15     End  
2  2020.11.02 16:00     New 
2  2020.11.02 16:00     Start 
2  2020.11.02 16:05     Stop   
2  2020.11.02 16:10     Start
2  2020.11.02 16:15     Stop   
2  2020.11.02 16:20     Start
2  2020.11.02 16:25     End
```

I need to get this result

```
ID SumTime
1  10 min
2  15 min
```

Comment: can yu explain how the 20 Minutes are derived from the data and of course also for the 180

Comment: this is an example but i have already corrected it

Comment: And which mysql Version?

Comment: MariaDB 10.5.11  
PHP 7.4.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF sort the dates and time and gives a row_number for all `start` and on the other side `end` or `stop`

And sums it up

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `ID` VARCHAR(20),
>   `Date` DATetime,
>   `Status` VARCHAR(5)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`ID`, `Date`, `Status`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '2020.11.02 15:00', 'New'),
>   ('1', '2020.11.02 15:00', 'Start'),
>   ('1', '2020.11.02 15:05', 'Stop'),
>   ('1', '2020.11.02 15:10', 'Start'),
>   ('1', '2020.11.02 16:15', 'End'),
>   ('2', '2020.11.02 16:00', 'New'),
>   ('2', '2020.11.02 16:00', 'Start'),
>   ('2', '2020.11.02 16:05', 'Stop'),
>   ('2', '2020.11.02 16:10', 'Start'),
>   ('2',  '2020.11.02 16:15', 'Stop'),
>   ('2', '2020.11.02 16:20', 'Start'),
>   ('2', '2020.11.02 16:25', 'End');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT t1.ID, SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,t1.`Date`,t2.`Date`)) complsum
> FROM (SELECT  *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `ID` ORDER BY `Date` ASC) AS row_num 
> FROM table1 WHERE `Status` =  'Start') t1 
> INNER JOIN (SELECT  *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `ID` ORDER BY `Date` ASC) AS row_num 
> FROM table1 WHERE `Status`  IN ('Stop','End')) t2 
> ON t1.ID = t2.ID AND t1.`row_num` =  t2.`row_num`
> GROUP BY t1.ID
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | complsum
> :- | -------:
> 1  |       70
> 2  |       15
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=66857eedcbca99debba35363a7877e59)*

Comment: what if i have more statuses which do not interfere with total time?

Comment: then you need to open a new question with the new stati

Comment: But in end effekt you always have a stus tht starts and ends, so oyu can use these to subrtact or add

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not at this stage of Mysql yet. Could you tell me what an inquiry with two new statuses "New_step, Restore) should look like. Both statuses do not interfere with the final time. I will be very grateful for your help